# GCP Bigquery - Time Travel - Max and Min Window time for a table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I understand the BigQuery provides 7 days time travel. I'm trying to get Max and Min of time travel possible for each table like Min and Max of timestamp. Is this information available in any of BigQuery metadata tables if not How is it possible to find out.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but it looks like the window can at least be set using sql commands: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-datasets#update_time_travel_windows. Presumably it can be queried with a get command? Not sure though.

Comment: Hi @LakshminarayananShanmugasunda, Did the above comment help you?

Comment: Apologies, I will try the comment from Michael Delgado and comment back in couple of days

Comment: Hi @Lakshminarayanan Shanmugasunda, The feature of time travel window is in [PRE-GA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel#configure_the_time_travel_window), you will have to enroll in the preview to use this feature.

Comment: Hi @Lakshminarayanan Shanmugasunda, If you find my answer helpful, please consider to accept & upvote it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their researches.

Answer (score 1):

The feature of the time travel window is in [Pre-GA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel#configure_the_time_travel_window), you will have to enroll in the preview to use this feature.

You can set the duration of the time travel window, from a minimum of two days to a maximum of seven days. Seven days is the default. You set the time travel window at the dataset level, which then applies to all of the tables within the dataset.

You can configure the time travel window to be longer in cases where it is more important to have the option of recovering the data, and to be shorter where that isn't a concern. Using a shorter time travel window allows you to save on storage costs. It can also allow you to conform to data retention policies that require hard deletion of data in a specific time frame.

To update the time travel window you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-datasets#update_time_travel_windows).